# How to exclude a class as a maven dependency from a jar that is not built with maven?

Tags: java, maven, javafx-2, javafx, maven-3

I'm trying to build a simple **javafx** application to consume a SOAP based web service when I'm reading *java web services : up and running* book (the question is not about java web services), I'm using :
 - netbeans 7.3
 - [javafx-maven-plugin 1.5](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin) for managing dependencies (I'm using [maven 3.0.4](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.0.4/release-notes.html))
 - [tiwulfx 1.1](http://tiwulfx.panemu.com/) to interact with POJOs

Here is my **POM** file :

```
<groupId>org.tarrsalah</groupId>
  <artifactId>teams-client</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.99</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>teams-client</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding> 
    <netbeans.hint.license>apache20</netbeans.hint.license>
  </properties> 

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency
    >
    <dependency>      
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.panemenu</groupId>
      <artifactId>tiwulfx</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>    
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>     

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>         
          <wsdlUrls>
            <wsdlUrl>http://localhost:8080/teams?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
          </wsdlUrls>
          <packageName>org.tarrsalah.teams.client.generated</packageName>          >
        </configuration>
      </plugin>            

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version> 1.5 </version>
        <configuration>         
          <mainClass>org.tarrsalah.teams.client.app.App</mainClass>
          <jarFileName>teams-client.jar</jarFileName>
          <vendor>tarrsalah</vendor>                                                           
        </configuration>                                    
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I downloaded the [tiwulfx](http://tiwulfx.panemu.com/) jar file and added all the dependencies in the **POM** file, and I installed it in my maven local repository (the project using netbeans/ant simple build and provide only a jar file).

I'm trying to build a self-contained runnable jar,when I run:
     mvn clean compile jfx:build-jar

I get this build error message:

```
[INFO] Java home is: /home/tarrsalah/local/jdk1.7.0_15/jre
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.445s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Feb 23 23:39:31 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/350M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:1.5:build-jar (default-cli) on project teams-client: Invocation of JavaFX method 'packageAsJar' failed with an error. It's possible this plugin is not compatible with the version of JavaFX you are using. InvocationTargetException: Error: Failed to create jar file teams-client-0.0.99-jfx.jar: duplicate entry: com/javafx/main/Main.class -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

it seems that javafx classes already included in the [tiwulfx](http://tiwulfx.panemu.com/) jar file and making conflict with the javafx classes in the JDK (I'm using 1.7u15) imported by the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin)  during the package phase.

this is how the tree dependencies looks like:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building teams-client 0.0.99
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ teams-client ---
[INFO] org.tarrsalah:teams-client:jar:0.0.99
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.panemenu:tiwulfx:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO]    \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.137s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Feb 24 00:21:34 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/163M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**My question is**: How can I exclude the javafx classes (the package) from the [tiwulfx](http://tiwulfx.panemu.com/) at the package phase ? it can be a trivial question because I'm new to maven ecosystem.

> **P.S: the jar generated after the operation works without any problems, I'm just trying to get a perfect build result.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to add the `tiwulfx` jar to your Maven repo by hand (it's not built by Maven and it's not hosted on a Maven repo anywhere), you might as well just repackage it by hand first. Just open the jar in a zip editor and delete the `com/javafx` folder. Then run the usual `install:install-file` goal.

When choosing a version number for the jar, it's a good idea to add an extra string to make it clear it's a slightly different jar from the one from the original website.

Comment: Thanks @artbristol , hope we can Get rid from this silly build hack in the next javafx 8:)

Comment: You might also want to contact panemu and request that they don't place the javafx code in their distributable jars - I don't really see any good reason for it to be in there in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Now TiwulFX is available in Maven.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.panemu</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiwulfx</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks.